Installing latest docker compose release on debian
I am trying to install an up-to date docker compose on debian so I can use the new include keyword and am getting a version mismatch between the apt info and docker compose version.
I have added the docker repository to my sources.list:
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian   bookworm stable

and apt is installing the packages from the docker repo:
$ sudo apt policy docker-compose-plugin
docker-compose-plugin:
  Installed: 2.25.0-1~debian.12~bookworm
  Candidate: 2.25.0-1~debian.12~bookworm
  Version table:
 *** 2.25.0-1~debian.12~bookworm 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bookworm/stable amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ apt policy docker-ce
docker-ce:
  Installed: 5:26.0.0-1~debian.12~bookworm
  Candidate: 5:26.0.0-1~debian.12~bookworm
  Version table:
 *** 5:26.0.0-1~debian.12~bookworm 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bookworm/stable amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

But docker compose version does show an old one:
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.2.3

In contrast, docker shows the right version:
$ docker --version
Docker version 26.0.0, build 2ae903e

Do I need to install docker compose via another method to get the newer functionality?
EDIT: As suggested in the answer, I found an outdated version of docker-compose in one of the binary folders (~/.docker/cli-plugins)

I've got docker-ce version 5.26 which seems to correspond to the right release?

If you have an outdated version of docker-compose hanging out in one of these directories, it may be taking priority:

/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
/usr/local/libexec/docker/cli-plugins
/usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins
/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins
~/.docker/cli-plugins

If you have an old docker-compose there, try deleting it. That should allow the version installed in docker-compose-plugin to take effect.
Source: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/11100#issuecomment-1771726824

I found an outdated docker-compose in ~/.docker/cli-plugins, thanks!
